# В какой опасности находятся файлы на сервере, не защищенные инструкцией deny from all?

Tags: php

Как правило, в папку с классами, совокупность которых образует движок сайта, добавляют файл `.htaccess` с `deny from all`. В деталях не заню, но это должно как минимум предотвратить доступ с папке из адресной строки браузера.

Вопрос: а что, доступ ко всем php-файлам, находящимся в корневой папке домена, можно получить из адресной строки?

Даже если это и так, то это было бы не страшно, если бы была возможность хранить все скрипты в папке `library`, защищённой файлом `.htaccess` с `deny from all`.
Тогда в корне можно было бы оставить только `index.php` и всякие мелочи типа `favicon`. Но мы не можем хранить хранить капчу в `library`, иначе

```
<img src="captcha.php" alt="" />
```

не отобразится. Мы не можем там хранить скрипт формы ввода, иначе

```
<form method="post" action="signin.php">
```

также не будет работать. Получается, что все эти файлы, которые не защищены `deny from all`, находятся в опасности? А ведь в `signin.php` мы работаем с личными данными пользователей (когда сверяем введённые данные с данными из базы данных).

Comment: Если делать единую точку входа (index.php) и определить как минмум константу с именем движка, или что угодно, и потом подгрузить все нужные фйлы проверяя наличие этой константы - проблем не будет. Видел такое

Comment: Сколько вопросов вы задаете, а ответ на них всегда примерно один: единая точка входа через `index.php`, вынести все остальные PHP-файлы за директорию, доступную по HTTP, роутинг, MVC и фреймворки. Почему бы наконец не прислушаться к советам?

Comment: К совету о единой точке уже прислушался и работаю над ней; в роутинг и MVC я ещё не въехал, а готовые движки использовать не буду; буду добиваться полного понимания на уровне нативного PHP.